# Android G1 latest installable version?

Tags: htc-dream

What is the latest installable version on an original Android G1 phone? Either vanilla or any kind of mod (CyanogenMod, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyanogenmod 6, which is 2.2 is reported to work for the T-mobile G1.

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVeKboqn6LU

Answer (score 2):

[COS-DS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=950765) is an Android 2.3 based ROM that I have been running for months on my ADP1 (identical to G1). It runs quite well although applications are starting to struggle with the limited RAM.

There are other 2.3 based ROMs but when I first wanted to switch to 2.3 this was the most stable and I have stuck with it since.

Answer (score 1):

[CyanogenMod 7.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1185027) has been unofficially ported to the Dream/Sapphire platform. This is an Android 2.3.5 based ROM with some of the heavy weight bits stripped out. It seems to run just fine on my ADP1.

Comment: Not only does this ROM seem to run better than anything I've ever put on my HTC_DREAM, it is newer than the CyanogenMod that I can get for my just acquired Nexus-S. Confound it all how is that fair?